# Memory leak in PowerShell in continuous run

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a powershell script that runs in a constant loop but it slowly eats up memory, even if I kill it the memory doesn't get released. I schedule this script to run on boot and only a reboot will free up the memory and haven't been able to find a way around this. If I slow down how often it checks the temperature it slows down eating up memory so it seems to be an issue with the switch but still can't find a way around this. Here is my code:

```
#######################################################################################R330FanControl.ps1###

# First and foremost, I cannot recommend using this or any script to alter system cooling or kill processes as it can cause damage or break stuff!
# I accept no liability for anything, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!
# CAUTION this sctipt could possibly damage things especially data but if your server is already cooking itself it should help lower the temperatures but know if it kills something as it’s writing data consider it lost!
# READ AND UNDERSTAND WHAT IT IS DOING SO YOU CAN MODIFY AS NEEDED

# REQUIRES ipmitools “OM-BMC-Dell-Web-WIN-9.1.0-2757_A00.exe” is what I downloaded from Dell at: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=9ngfj
# Add to the system variable path the installation folder which might be different from “C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\bmc” where the ipmitool.exe is located.

# Setup
# create a scheduled task to run on startup that calls powershell.exe with the following parameter(remove the # before the -file part):
# -file “C:\Scripts\PS\R330FanControl\R330FanControl.ps1″
# Set to run with highest privledges and without being logged in, be sure it’s enabled and reboot. Then verify it’s running in the background.

#Variables###################################

# Set iDRAC IP
$iDRAC=”XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX”
# Set iDRAC Credentials
$usr=”root”
$pw=”calvin”

#Reset counter
$i=0

# Enables fan control via ipmitool
$FanControlEnable = “ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00”

# DISABLE FAN CONTROL if you ever want to do so.
# ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x01

# Sets fan speed to % defined in $FanControl variable
# hex conversion tables http://cactus.io/resources/toolbox/decimal-binary-octal-hexadecimal-conversion
$FanControl20 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x14”)
$FanControl30 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x1e”)
$FanControl40 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x28”)
$FanControl50 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x32”)
$FanControl60 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x3c”)
$FanControl70 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x46”)
$FanControl80 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x50”)
$FanControl90 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x5a”)
$FanControl100 = (“ipmitool -I lanplus -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x64”)

#######################
$KillHighCPU = “C:\Scripts\PS\R330FanControl\Kill_CPU_hog.ps1”
#######################
# Retrieves temperatures:
# ipmitool -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw -I lanplus sdr elist | findstr “Temp” | findstr “0Eh”

#############################################

Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControlEnable

While($true)
{
$i++
$cpuTemp = (ipmitool -H $iDRAC -U $usr -P $pw -I lanplus sdr elist | findstr “Temp” | findstr “0Eh” | %{$_.split(‘|’)[4]})

# Extract the digits of the temperature
$cpuTempDigits=$cpuTemp.Substring(0,3)

# Displays the temerature as the script is running
$cpuTempDigits

# Switch logic to change the fan based on operating temperature reported via ipmi. (I noticed this displays different temperatures thatn Speccy, not sure which is more accurate)
# My processor is a e3-1220 V6 which from what I could find has a maximum temperature of ~70°C
# The last temperature from 67-999C will invoke another script tha twill find and kill the process usign the most CPU resources, THIS COULD POTENTIALLY BE DANGEROUS!
switch ($cpuTempDigits) {
{1..49 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 20%” ; Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl20}
{50..52 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 30%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl30}
{53..54 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 40%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl40}
{55..56 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 50%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl50}
{57..58 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 60%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl60}
{59..60 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 70%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl70}
{61..62 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 80%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl80}
{63..64 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 90%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl90}
{65..66 -contains $_}{write-host “Fan set to 100%” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $FanControl100}
{67..999 -contains $_}{write-host “Killing processes to cool down!” ;Invoke-Expression -Command $KillHighCPU}

}
# IF YOU ARE MANUALLY RUNNING THIS SCRIPT you can uncomment out the line below to watch it display the number of times it’s checking temps and setting the fan speeds.
#Write-Host “Action has run $i times at” (date)
}

#################################################################################
```

Here's the kill the process that's hogging the CPU:

```
#################################################################################

### Kill_CPU_Hog.ps1 ###
# First and foremost, I cannot recommend using this or any script to alter system cooling or kill processes as it can cause damage or break stuff!
# I accept no liability for anything, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!
# CAUTION this sctipt could possibly damage things especially data but if your server is already cooking itself it should help lower the temperatures but know if it kills something as it’s writing data consider it lost!
# This is the second script that finds what is taking the most CPU usage and kills that process. This script should not be run on it’s own.
# This script is invoked by the R330FanControl script that only calls it if the CPU temperature is running too hot and the fans are spinning as fast as they can to keep it cool and it’s still not enough.
# Then this script is invoked to kill whatever is potentially causing the server to overheat.
# https://www.youtube.com/c/ShinyTechThings

#Get all cores, which includes virtual cores from hyperthreading
$cores = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
#Get all process with there ID’s, excluding processes you can’t stop.
$processes = ((Get-Counter “\Process(*)\ID Process”).CounterSamples).where({$_.InstanceName -notin “idle”,”_total”,”system”})
#Get cpu time for all processes
$cputime = $processes.Path.Replace(“id process”, “% Processor Time”) | get-counter | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples
#Get the processes with above 14% utilisation.
$highUsage = $cputime.where({[Math]::round($_.CookedValue / $cores,2) -gt 14})
# For each high usage process, grab it’s process ID from the processes list, by matching on the relevant part of the path
$highUsage |%{
$path = $_.Path
$id = $processes.where({$_.Path -like “*$($path.Split(‘(‘)[1].Split(‘)’)[0])*”}) | select -ExpandProperty CookedValue
Stop-Process -Id $id -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

#################################################################################
```

Comment: First of all, replace all those ugly, curly 'smart-quotes' `“` and `”` by straight ones `"`. They may look nice on web pages or in Word documents, but should not be used in code. (Same goes for the single-quotes `‘` and `’` --> `'`)

Comment: the usual recommendation is to NEVER run powershell continuously. it tends to eat up RAM or to hang or to simply vanish. if you need things run "semi-always" then you should use task scheduler for short runs that end fairly quickly OR re-write your code to use c#.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @RegEdit - thank you, but that seems wrong to me since it doesn't answer the Question ... instead, it advises to side step the problem. in my opinion, an Answer would show the actual source of the problem ... and i have no idea where the leak is coming from. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey totally but in this case I'd say it does answer the question: Q just states there's a memory leak, and OP ends with "still can't find a way around this". You are providing a way round it imo.

Comment: @RegEdit - done! [*grin*] please, let me know if you think of any reasonably short & simple improvements.

Comment: It's probably less memory to not create integer arrays on every loop:  `{$_ -ge 1 -and $_ -le 49}`.  You probably don't need invoke-expression.  Is there a sleep between loops?

Answer (score 3):

*[edit - note that this is based on reading the posts from others and my own experience with other scripting lingos. that means it **aint** fact, it's logic and anecdote. [*grin*]]*

this is a kinda-sorta Answer, not a real one. [*sigh ...*]

the usual recommendation is to NEVER run powershell continuously. it has an unfortunate habit of eating up RAM, or hanging, or simply vanishing. that does not *always* happen, but it happens often enuf that one is strongly recommended to avoid running any PoSh instance for any extended length of time.

if you NEED long run times, then try to break it into shorter runs. perhaps use Task Scheduler to run the code in frequent but SHORT runs.

a better solution is to rewrite your code in something with tighter memory management, tho. perhaps c# ... [*grin*]

Comment: I have not had experience with PowerShell having unexplained memory usage on long runs, nor it hanging or "vanishing". Like any other code, you can do things in PowerShell that can cause overuse of resources. I also think the suggestion that C# has "tighter" memory management needs citation; both languages run in .Net and use the same garbage collector.

Comment: @briantist - as i pointed out, my Answer is not really up to what i consider an Answer. i have seen reports on the Powershell subreddit of long-running PoSh code that would start eating RAM, or hang, or - in a few cases - PoSh simply stopped running at all and apparently crashed with none of the expected "it crashed" leftovers. i am far too inexperienced to go into any detail about, tho. **_please_** feel free to write a better Answer ... i will remove mine and "useful vote" yours. [*grin*]

Comment: I don't necessarily think it needs to be removed (also I'm not the downvoter fwiw), but I think it's worth noting where some of the information comes from and maybe a distinction between "this is fact" vs. "I've had [or seen others have] this experience in these situations"

Comment: On Reddit someone has the same issue doing something similar but was never solved. It ran fine on Windows server 2012 but not 2016. I'm running on WS 2019 so it appears to be a OS implementation of something different with PowerShell. I may re-write in C# but would prefer to run in PowerShell natively.

Comment: Also I'll say that the advice of replacing longer runs with shorter and more frequent task scheduler runs _is_ sound and I use it often, as a means of guarding against other issues where memory leaks (that would have affected similar C# code) or other weirdness. If I really want lightning fast reaction, I let the script have its infinite loop, and instruct task scheduler to run the process every 5 minutes with no duplicates, and kill it every 24 hours. That way it's nearly always running in realtime, if it dies, it's restarted within 5 mins, and every 24 hours it will be refreshed from scratch

Comment: @briantist - kool! thank you for the feedback. i added a "Not a fact" note as a prefix to the "kinda-sorta Answer". [*grin*]

Comment: Fo what its worth, I;ve had more than one PS script that simply kept eating RAM the longer it ran. Even if I've coded to not store values in variables PS can behave as is that's what's happening

Answer (score 2):

Memory used by PowerShell generally can't be locked outside of its process, and the majority of the work your script is doing is really shelling out to an executable; one which deals with low-level hardware which means it must interact with a driver (or a background service which deals with the driver).

I suspect that either the external executable is not exiting (though you'd likely notice hundreds of them) or that the memory leak is in the service or driver.

It would be helpful if you showed evidence of where the system is reporting the memory usage (in a PowerShell.exe process, in a different process, generally as paged/non-paged kernel memory, as cached, etc.) by looking at task manager.

Comment: Task manager actually doesn't identify a process consuming the memory. I dug into it and from what I remember it was non-paged but will have to re-confirm. There's no IPMITOOL processed left behind so it appears that it is closing properly.

Comment: yeah non-paged pool sounds to me like a leak in the driver, which unfortunately means you might not be able to get around it on this system :(